# What is the value of ADA locked in a Native token?

Tags: nft, native-assets

I was wondering, if ADA locked  in an native asset is equally valuable? For me it is like if somebody put a draw on a ticket but there are other implications:  it can give trouble when making transactions because it adds to the transactions size. Should we accept a payment of 500 ADA that have native assets be as valuable as one without Native Assets? Can we stake ADA along with native assets... or this locked value can not be staked?

EDIT: I mean min ADA needed for moving this ADA together with the native assets.

EDIT: For example you are asking for 500 ADA as payment for some work, but they send you 500 ADA with 200 NFT, if those NFT have not value in any marketplace, would this payment be equally valuable as a payment with only 500 ADA?

Comment: Are you referring to the minimum ADA value attached to each UTxO?

Comment: Yes I will update

Answer (score 3):

ADA locked in an asset is equally valuable only insofar as you trust the underlying logic of the script address that keeps it locked. Assuming the smart contract is bulletproof, then yes - it is reasonable to say that a 500-ADA token is worth the same as 500 ADA.

Staking however is a bit more complicated. Currently, there is no way to stake anything other than raw ADA on L1. This does not mean that other tokens won't be stake-able in the future (see my answer [here](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4562/can-you-stake-stablecoins-such-as-djed/4563#4563) on the matter). Once new staking structures are set up on sidechains/hdyra heads, and eventually maybe even on L1, you'd be able to stake any token to any node willing to accept such a token as a form of stake.

On a different note, clever use of pointer addresses may make it possible to maintain staking rights over native-asset locked-values. For example, I could set up a script address that guards the 500 ADA with a pointer component that gives the receiver of the asset staking rights to the guarded ADA. Although, I'd imagine this could get cumbersome and difficult to trade.

Comment: What about if the locked asset has a undesirable IPFS hash... so every time you open your Wallet you see a disgusting image? like a ticket with a ugly message written in? also the Native Assets make cumbersome to make the transactions perse

Comment: Also every transaction that happens carring native assets is more vulnerable to get: outPut to Big error, as well as pay more fees, because the Tx Size is bigger. And makes harder to find any native asset needed in your Wallet, and if you have a big quantity of NFTs in a single UTXO, this UTXOs is harder to be used by the above remarks

Answer (score 1):

Ada isn't locked in a native asset. The native asset requires an associated amount of ada held in a utxo at a minimum. In the case above of 500 Ada + 1 token, a transaction can be created with two outputs, one of 497 Ada and one of 2 ada with a fee of 1 Ada (high fee, using it for simplicity. In reality, it will be smaller). You can also combine assets from multiple utxos into a single one to have a smaller minutxo required to hold the assets to reclaim some of the Ada if someone sends you a token + 1.5 ada for exmaple.

Comment: " The native asset requires an associated amount of ADA held in a utxo at a minimum" that's what i mean with locked.